# how in angularjs we can achieve the object update which is based on some other objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am trying to update values of variables `b` and `c` with an add method (simply incrementing their value) but `a` (the sum of the two) is not reflecting this operation.

I understand we can use a `$scope.$watch` function to update them, but I have an application with many objects dependent on other objects. If my dependent object changes I want my object to also changes without using any $watchers.

This is just a simple example where I am trying to get `$scope.a` and `$scope.obj.a` value updated with the help of watchers. How do I do this?

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    a : {{a}}<br />
    b: {{b}}<br />
    c: {{c}}<br />
    <button ng-click="add();">Add</button>
    <br /><br /><br />

    obj.a : {{obj.a}}<br />
    obj.b: {{obj.b}}<br />
    obj.c: {{obj.c}}<br />
    <button ng-click="obj.add();">obj.Add</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.b = 1;
            $scope.c = 2;
            $scope.a = $scope.b + $scope.c;


            $scope.$watch('b', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.a = $scope.b + $scope.c;
            });
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.b++;
                $scope.c++;
            };

            //this is object with dot property example
            $scope.obj = {};
            $scope.obj.b = 1;
            $scope.obj.c = 2;

            $scope.obj.a = $scope.obj.b + $scope.obj.c;


            $scope.$watch('obj.b', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $scope.obj.a = $scope.obj.b + $scope.obj.c;
            });
            $scope.obj.add = function () {
                $scope.obj.b++;
                $scope.obj.c++;
            };
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring a (or obj.a respectively) as a function instead of an object / object property. The function will automatically by re-executed by Angular each time any of the properties it uses change and therefore your "a" values will change without the need for you to explicitly define the watches.

See your updated code below:

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.b = 1;
            $scope.c = 2;
            $scope.a = function() {return $scope.b + $scope.c};        
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.b++;
                $scope.c++;
            };

            //this is object with dot property example
            $scope.obj = {};
            $scope.obj.b = 1;
            $scope.obj.c = 2;
            $scope.obj.a = function() {
              return $scope.obj.b + $scope.obj.c;
            }


            $scope.obj.add = function () {
                $scope.obj.b++;
                $scope.obj.c++;
            };
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    a : {{a()}}<br />
    b: {{b}}<br />
    c: {{c}}<br />
    <button ng-click="add();">Add</button>
    <br /><br /><br />

    obj.a : {{obj.a()}}<br />
    obj.b: {{obj.b}}<br />
    obj.c: {{obj.c}}<br />
    <button ng-click="obj.add();">obj.Add</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's fine and it's a good solution but is there anyway that can be done over object only? (just curious)

Comment: Not really. When you declare a as a property (with a = b + c) you are telling Angular that a equals b + c **at the time of declaration only**, not that it should always equal b + c. Therefore Angular does not know that it should update it for you. This is why you need a function, which effectively means a should equal b + c at all times.